# Jquery hover effect stops working after successful ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my code, I've hover event to show one div & ajax code to replace the content of that particular div. What happens is as soon as the div gets updated with ajax request, hover event stops working. It may be because in DOM, it wouldn't be able to find particular function or something, but I'm not able to figure it out. I'm using jquery version 1.11.
Here's my code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#a').hover(function(e){
    $("#b").css("display","block");
  });
  $(document).delegate('.buynow','click', function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "xyz.php",
            context: this,
            data: {type:type},
            success: function(option){
                   $('#a').empty();
                   $('#a').replaceWith(option);
                }
        });
        e.preventDefault;
    }
   });
});
</script>
```

**NOTE**
`#a` is present on successful ajax request, `<div id='a'>...</div>` is the code that's being replaced.

Any idea why hover doesn't work? I already tried with `live` & `on`, but that didn't help, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `event-delegation` in this context, since you are replacing the old elements with newer one with same id, And by the way instead of using `.hover()` just use `mouseenter`

```
  $(document).on('mouseenter','#a',function(e){
    $("#b").css("display","block");
  });
```

Comment: a is not loaded dynamically its there only content is changed

Comment: @EhsanSajjad No.. please read the full question. See the note give by the op.

Comment: Perfect, that worked like a charm. And sure will use mouseenter, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

try below code and use .one http://api.jquery.com/one/ and also use `mouseenter` event instead of `hover`:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#a').on('mouseenter', function(e){
    $("#b").css("display","block");
  });

  $(".buynow").one('click', function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "xyz.php",
            context: this,
            data: {type:type},
            success: function(option){
                   $('#a').empty();
                   $('#a').replaceWith(option);
                }
        });
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but `one` is not something in my requirement. And in fact that will change the entire scenario of my code. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your code like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#a').hover(function(e){
    $("#b").css("display","block");
  });
  $(document).delegate('.buynow','click', function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "xyz.php",
            context: this,
            data: {type:type},
            success: function(option){
                   $('#a').empty();
                   $('#a').replaceWith(option);


 // add hover again after replacing
 $('#a').hover(function(e){
    $("#b").css("display","block");
  }); 

                }
        });
        e.preventDefault;
    }
   });
});
</script>
```